# How to pass if division by zero appears

Tags: python, error-handling, divide-by-zero

I have a long function to do a NLTK task which also calculates the ratio of several things like `sum(adj)/len(words)`.

Sometimes it´s possible that the words are zero which then occures an error. I tried it with something like this

```
def nltk_process(dict_bp):
        try:
                #do all the stuff and then calculate several ratios
                verhaeltnis_adj_verb = "Verhältnis ADJ/VERB: " + str(dict.get('ADJ')/dict.get('VERB'))  # just an example where sometimes it devides by zero 
        except:
                pass
```

I use the function in a big for loop to do this on about 800 MySQL tables. It works for the most if I f.e. break the loop after 10 iterations. But then in some of the data it devides by zero which makes everything not work.

So is there any simple solution to this? Why does the try and except not work on my function?

error:

```
global filtered_sentence_verhaeltnis
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

`filtered_sentence_verhaeltnis = ("Sentence Sentiment gefiltert: " + str(sum(filtered_sentence_sent)/len(filtered_sentence_sent)))`

EDIT//

My code looks something like this:

```
for i in dict_bp.values():
        nltk_process(i)
```

in this `nltk_process` sometimes it gets the error because of the empty values of the dict. So I need something to make my `nltk_process` function to not error everything, just keep continueing if an error occures.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use dict as a parameter value, since that is already used by the language

Comment: true I use dict_bp actually. I update. Thx

Comment: what do you want your code to do when it hits a divide by 0 case? I assume there is more to your function where you use `verhaeltnis_adj_verb` but that variable wouldn't be set if you got a divide by 0. If you're still getting exceptions, they're not coming from this spot, `try except` like that will catch and silence anything.

Comment: I added the error I hit. I just want to make it continue the loop where I execute the function. So that for this table it has just no results.

Comment: You're certain the line you're getting the error from is wrapped in a `try except`? because it should catch all exceptions

Comment: I just tried a divide by zero inside a `try`/`except` block and it worked just fine.  What aren't you showing us?

Comment: @MarkRansom so the code looks like this as example: `for i in dict_bp.values(): nltk_process(i)` so the `nltk_process` runs several times- most of the time well, but sometimes it devides by zero! and i want the loop to continue and just return nothing. I use the variables for another operation: I add it to an excel sheet. As I said not so easy, lots of components. The thing is I want to keep it simple. So if there is an error, just pass ;)

Comment: As I said, it works for me.  You need to do a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or you won't get any help.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help.  There still isn't a block of code that will reliably fail the way you say it does.

Comment: So the reason why the error appears is that `filtered_sentence_sent`is empty and `filtered_sentence_verhaeltnis = ("Sentence Sentiment gefiltert: " + str(sum(filtered_sentence_sent)/len(filtered_sentence_sent)))`devides by zero. As I asked, is there a way to set the whole function in between `try and except` to make it easy?

Comment: Hello everybody. So i have new information. The table which I want to fetch from the MySQL database is empty. Thats why such error occures. Obviously all the evaluations in the function aren´t working if they have noting to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

So I fixed it. I used `try and except` but not in the function itself. I had to use it in the loop where I call the function.

Now it looks like this:

```
def export_all_to_excel(dict_bp):                                                                  
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Export_ALL.xlsx")                                        
    z = 0                                                                                       
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Analyse')                                           
    for key,values in dict_bp.items():                                                             
        z += 1                                                                                  
        try:                                                                                    
            nltk_einzelauswahl(list(values))
            #some more stuff                                                                     
            worksheet.write('G{}'.format(z), sentence_sent_verhaeltnis)                         
        except:                                                                                 
            worksheet.write('A{}'.format(z), key)                                               
            worksheet.write('B{}'.format(z), "Some error occured")                                                                                                 
    workbook.close()
```